# Not allow Nested SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

I have 2 `SqlCommand`'s, one of them is nested. Why it does not allow me to issue the second `SqlCommand` (I am using a separate `SQLCommand`)? It gives an error

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

If I use a separate `SqlConnection`, it is fine.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, cn);

 SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 while (rd.Read())
 {
      ....    
      try
      {
          SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(qry2, cn);
          cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          // I get this error here
          // System.Data; There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
      }        
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is obvious: you can't use same connection for different `SqlCommand` instance at the same time while `DataReader` is still open. The [`SqlDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) instance explanation already said that:

> While the SqlDataReader is being used, the associated SqlConnection is
>   busy serving the SqlDataReader, and *no other operations can be
>   performed on the SqlConnection other than closing it*. This is the case
>   until the Close method of the SqlDataReader is called. For example,
>   you cannot retrieve output parameters until after you call Close.

The common solution for this problem is using `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` on connection string:

```
<add name="ConnectionName" connectionString="[connection string];MultipleActiveResultSets=True" ... />
```

Then, use `DataTable` instead iterating `DataReader` directly:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(rd);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    // other stuff

    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(qry2, cn);
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // throw exception
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can put simple check if the previous connection is still open (i.e. serving `DataReader`) using [`SqlConnection.State`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.state(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
// close if connection still open
if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    cn.Close();
}

// open if connection already closed
if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    cn.Open();
}
```

The simple checks above should be put on any part of code which requesting `SqlConnection`.